# abstract linear algebra vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the set $\{1, (t-1), (t-1)^2, (t-1)^3\}$ generates $P_3$ the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq3$.

I just started to learn algebra, so I basically do not know how to start. I would be thankful if anyone can give me a comprehensive answer.

Comment: This follows from the Taylor expansion around $x=1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @lhf Good catch!

Comment: @R.M. Can you see why it is enough to prove that set is *linearly independent*?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, if the lin. comb. of the elements in the set is 0, then the coeff. are 0.

Comment: @R.M. Well, there you go, as that is rather simple to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to respond to "I basically do not know how to start".

Try "simpler" problems:

- Show that the set $\{1, (t-1), (t-1)^2, (t-1)^3\}$ is linearly independent.
- Given $f(t)\in P_3$, write $f$ as a linear combination of these four polynomials.

---

[Added:] It depends on how you understand "generates". If it means "spans", then you can ignore the first problem.

Comment: yes, i think it means spans. so i don't need to show lin. indep.?

Comment: Yes. It is true though.

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_0 = 1, q_1= t-1, q_2=(t-1)^2, q_3=(t-1)^3$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{q_0 \\ q_1 \\ q_2 \\ q_3}
=
\pmatrix{
\hphantom- 1 & \hphantom-0 & \hphantom-0 & 0 \\
-1 & \hphantom-1 & \hphantom-0 & 0 \\
\hphantom-1 & -2 & \hphantom-1 & 0 \\
-1 & \hphantom-3 & -3 & 1 \\
}
\pmatrix{1 \\ t \\ t^2 \\ t^3 }
$$
The matrix is nonsingular and so $1, t, t^2, t^3$ can be written as a linear combination of $q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3$.
This observation suffices to answer the question. Nevertheless, the inverse of this matrix is easy to find and we can be explicit:
$$
\pmatrix{1 \\ t \\ t^2 \\ t^3 }
=
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
}
\pmatrix{q_0 \\ q_1 \\ q_2 \\ q_3}
$$

Comment: thanks... but i haven't got that far to understand nonsingular...

Comment: @R.M., it means that the matrix has an inverse, which in this case is easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Every polynomial $p$ of degree less than or equal to $3$ can be written as
$$
p(t) = a_3 t^3 + a_2 t^2 + a_1 t + a_0,
$$
where the $a_i$ live in your field (I assume you're looking at polynomials with real coefficients, although this doesn't matter). So, we can see that every such polynomial (i.e., every element of the vector space $P_3$) can be written as a linear combination of $1$, $t$, $t^2$, and $t^3$. If we can show that each of these elements is in the span of the set you give, we will be done (do you see why?).

First, we see $1$ is in the set itself, so we're good there. Now, $t\not\in S = \{1, t - 1, (t - 1)^2, (t - 1)^3\}$, but $t = (t - 1) + 1$, so $t$ is in the span of $S$, which is what we wanted. Similarly, $t^2\not\in S$, but $t^2 - 2t + 1$ is, and $-1 = -1\cdot 1$, and $2t$ are in the span of $S$, so $(t^2 - 2t + 1) + 2t - 1 = t^2$ is in the span of $S$. It only remains to show that $t^3$ is in the span of $S$. Can you check the details to your satisfaction and finish the argument from here?

Comment: yes, so $(t-1)^3=t^3-3t^2+3t+1\in span(S)$, since we showed $t^2\in span(S), t\in span(S), 1\in span(S)$, then we get $t^3\in span(S)$. Is that right?

Comment: @R.M. That's exactly it!